# FMUException: Error loading the binary. Could not load the FMU binary

Tags: python, binary, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia-jetson-nano, pyfmi

How do i solve this problem?
[image]

The operation system environment is as follows.

- python 3.7.1
- conda 4.5.12

[image]

Comment: Welcome! It may help you to edit your question based on [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

The FMU binary seem to have some dependencies that cannot be found on your machine. This would indicate that either the FMU is not compatible with the linux version you are running or the FMU is not correctly generated (i.e. it should be self contained and not needing any external binary dependencies). To check which, you can manually unzip your FMU, and in a terminal browse to the binary that is contained in the subfolder (binaries/linux64) and run "ldd .so" this will show you the dependencies of the FMU binary.